# Replace componentWillMount with a method which will run before child component life cycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    state = { error: null };

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
            this.setState({ error });
        });
    }
```

Do not want to use componentWillMount because it gives warning. Can not use componentDidMount because it runs after end of child component life cycle. Do not want to use getDerivedStateFromProps because it runs in every re-render. So how can I replace componentWillMount and what would be the solution.

Comment: Actually, this is the way that React works. You can't change it or invent something new (Actually you can do this by modifying life cycles but this is not recommended at all) for your purpose. If you really want to make a request before the component gets mounted, you should consider using the SSR application.